# How to fetch parameter value from string with linux command

Tags: linux, string, search

I want to value of RequestID parameter from the below string with linux command.

```
"2019-12-05 07:55:59","3c331c0f-8657-4fae-880d-351c7f41024f","info","Method : {_FLR}     Request  =>{LoginId=>42483357 ,RequestId=>546677 ,BatchId=>6 ,ServiceID=>2  ,Amount=>20000 ,From=>07058717569 ,Email=>admin@n.com ,}"
```

Above is the string and I need result 546677.

I have series of this kind of string I want value of RequestID parameter(value will be deferent)

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

If I get this right, you are running some shell command? Then you could forward your output into another program's input using the pipe `|` op.

To filter some text use `grep` with a regEx and then `tee` to create a file from the filtered output (if you have multiple strings in your output)

```
echo "RequestId=>546677" | grep "RequestId=>\d{6}" | tee logfile.txt
```

At best create your own regEx as I don't have any info about your case here.

Comment: value lenght is not fix

Comment: I have full string which I have pasted on comment and I need just RequestID value which is 546677 in result. I will have file of this kind string and I will run shell command on each line to get value of RequestID from all string.

Comment: you could change it to "RequestId=>\d*" to match any length. Best check it yourself with tools like https://regex101.com/

Comment: it is giving whole string again